# How to obtain the latitude and longitude corresponding to a point on android device screen using GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, screen, latitude-longitude

I am working on GoogleMap. I need to get the latitude and longitude corresponding to the four corners of the GoogleMap which is currently visible to me on my android device screen.

Its not possible to use
 map.getProjection().fromPixels(map.getWidth()-1, map.getHeight()-1);

as 'map' is not a MapView,but its a GoogleMap.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VisibleRegion.farLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion.html#farLeft), farRight, nearLeft and nearRight is what you need.

Comment: Is it possible to set the latitude and longitude of the VisibleRegion programmatically when the map loads?I mean the values for farLeft, nearRight,etc...

Answer (score 1):

Use on your GoogleMap

```
LatLngBounds llBounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
LatLng sW = latLngBounds.southwest;
LatLng nE = latLngBounds.northeast;
```

`LatLng` contains the latitude and longitude attributes

```
double north = nE.latitude;
double south = sW.latitude;
double east = nE.longitude;
double west = sW.longitude;
```

And calculate the other two coords

[Reference, API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds)